# How to limit the number of selected color checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to coding and am trying to limit the user to selecting a maximum of two color options. I can't figure out where I am going wrong in the code.

```
<label class="container" for="red">Red
    <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="red">
    <span class="checkmark red"></span>
</label>

<label class="container" for="blue">Blue
    <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="blue">
    <span class="checkmark blue"></span>
</label>

<label class="container" for="green">Green
    <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="green">
    <span class="checkmark green"></span>
</label>

<label class="container" for="yellow">Yellow
    <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="yellow">
    <span class="checkmark yellow"></span>
</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var limit = 2;
    $('input.single-check').on('change', function(evt) {
        if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi, you have to think about at least two states of operation.  You check an unchecked item and you check a checked item.  In either case the "on change" event is being caught before the "change" is applied.  You probably need to find out the current "checked" status of `$this)` before just setting it to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `.siblings` to reference the other inputs, but they are not siblings because they are all nested within labels.

You don't need to find them relative to your selected item, you can just find them all directly like this:

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
        if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > limit) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
  });
```

(Also, if you want to select a maximum of 2 then your test should be `> limit`, not `>= limit`)

Comment: Hey Will, thanks for the feedback. Your code works perfectly. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the checkboxes are not siblings. You need to change your logic to select all checkboxes, then count the number of them which have been checked, which you can do with `filter()`, like this:

```js
var limit = 2;
var $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(evt) {
  if ($checkboxes.filter(':checked').length > limit) {
    this.checked = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="container" for="red">Red
  <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="red">
  <span class="checkmark red"></span>
</label>

<label class="container" for="blue">Blue
  <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="blue">
  <span class="checkmark blue"></span>
</label>

<label class="container" for="green">Green
  <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="green">
  <span class="checkmark green"></span>
</label>

<label class="container" for="yellow">Yellow
  <input class="single-check" type="checkbox" id="yellow">
  <span class="checkmark yellow"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Hey Rory, thanks for the feedback. Your code works perfectly. Thanks a ton!